# Seeking WPS Client

Tags: geoserver, software-recommendations, wps

I would want to have a simple WPS client, that would work with GeoServer. QGis (1.8.0, Lisboa) WPS plugin (v1.1.0) doesn't work*. Any client that is SIMPLE to use, user friendly, will do (the one built in GeoServer as demo is perfect, but I'd like a third party client).
It could either be a desktop client, or a web client. I tried using OpenLayers but I got a .js file that had to be incorporated to a web page and I am no programmer to know how to do it. A simple webpage with cute little buttons is what I want.

Do you know of an existing open-source program that does support OGC standards (WPS mainly), or simple tutorials on how to set up a web client?

---

Running on Win XP.